# VBA SELENIUM doesnt find element (table )

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

**i'm new on vba and sorry for my english**, I have written a VBA which opens a web link using selenium edge web driver to scrape of table and I got several problems with which I need your advice on guys.

[code of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WFvl.png)

[my code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAnS9.png)

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Better post the relevant section of the html output together with your question. A lot of the html code is collapsed or not visible in the image. Also we cannot test the vba code because it is in an image

Comment: Welcome light! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your first badge. We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how...  https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

This VBA code should work. I have left the steps I went through to derive the XPath in as comments. Hope this helps. Otherwise it is very simple.

```
Option Explicit
Sub sbOuterHTML()
    Dim driver As ChromeDriver
    Set driver = New ChromeDriver
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim sHTML As String
    Dim we As WebElement
    sURL = "https://davetallett26.github.io/table.html"
    Call driver.Start("edge")
    driver.get (sURL)
    driver.Window.Maximize
    sbDelay (100000)
    Set we = driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body")
'    Print #1, we.FindElementByXPath("/html/body").Attribute("outerHTML")
'    Print #1, we.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div/table").Attribute("outerHTML")
'    Print #1, we.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr").Attribute("outerHTML")
'    Print #1, we.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]").Attribute("outerHTML")
'    Print #1, we.FindElementByXPath("//input").Attribute("outerHTML")
'    Print #1, we.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/following::input[1]").Attribute("outerHTML")
'    Print #1, we.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/following::input[1]").Attribute("name")
'    Print #1, we.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/following::input[1]").Attribute("id")
    sHTML = we.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/following::input[2]").Attribute("id")
    sbPrint (sHTML)
    sbDelay (100000)
    driver.Quit
End Sub

Sub sbDelay(delay As Long): Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To delay:  DoEvents: Next i: End Sub 'old skool delay
Sub sbPrint(sText As String): Open "C:\tmp\z-" & Format(Now(), "HHMMSS") & ".txt" For Output As #1: Print #1, sText: Close #1: End Sub
```